# How to extract text outside of a html tag using jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

I have the following HTML code:

```
    Data                       


    <div class="alg"></div>
    <div class="alg"></div>





    Pepsi
    791



    <div class="alg"></div>
    <div class="alg"></div>


    Coke
    700



    <div class="gap"></div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
```

I want to extract all values Coke,700,pepsi,791. I tried the following code using Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("div.alg") ) // Select all the div tags
{
    TextNode next = (TextNode) element.nextSibling(); // Get the next node of each div as a TextNode

    System.out.println(next.text()); // Print the text of the TextNode
}
```

But the above code always print "" empty string.

Comment: I have a test on my mac and seem your code work as expected. What did you load the HTML file?

Comment: @ThanhTRANCONG I downloaded the html file from server and pass it to jsoup.

Comment: Can it happen by difference version of Jsoup? Mine is 1.8.3, what's yours?

Comment: mine is 1.9.2 and I have also tried on my mac machine, any way I can debug this?

Comment: Can you send me the link to download html file?

Comment: Remember that jsoup cannot parse if that document is populated by Javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127241/discussion-between-user818455-and-thanh-tran-cong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000);
for( Element element : doc.select(".gap") ) { // Select all the div tags
    Node next = element.nextSibling();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (next instanceof TextNode) {
        sb.append(((TextNode)next).text());
        next = next.nextSibling();
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Print the text of the TextNode
}
```